# How to get a file's timestamp in spotfire?

Tags: timestamp, ironpython, spotfire

I have a spotfire template that runs every night using scheduler and I want to show its last refresh time on the template. Is there anyway I can do it within native spotfire functionality or using IronPython ?

Comment: Where do you want to display this? By scheduler I assume you mean you are loading it into the web player memory via scheduled updates?

Comment: I want to display the file's last update time in a Text area inside the template after it is done with processing

Comment: Checkout [this thread](https://community.tibco.com/questions/how-display-last-refreshed-data-time-schedule-report-spotfire) and [this one](http://www.tibco.com/blog/2014/02/09/displaying-timestamps-in-a-text-area/)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to add an extra column to one Information Link you are using or have an separate Information link only with this column element, say "Schedule Refresh Time".

Initially do not be concerned about what is the DB table or column you are using, just pull any column with data type DateTime.

Now add this column to your information link and edit SQL. Here find the column you added in SQL query, and replace the column from something

T1."Any Column" as "Schedule Refresh Time"

To something like

SYSDATE as "Schedule Refresh Time".

Done.
From now onwards, whenever the Scheduled update will be pull data from Information Link, this column will capture current server Time and that is time of scheduled refresh.